# Upper Bound for $\frac{\mathrm{d}^ke^{x^m}}{\mathrm{d}x^k}$

Tags: derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, upper-lower-bounds

A function that is Taylor expandable about $x = a$ can be written as
$$
f(x)=f(a)+f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)+\frac{f^{\prime \prime}(a)}{2 !}(x-a)^{2}+\cdots+\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k !}(x-a)^{k}+R_{k+1}(x)$$
where $R_{k+1}=\frac{f^{(k+1)}\left(\xi\right)}{(k+1) !}(x-a)^{k+1}$ for some $\xi$ between $a$ an $x$.

I have a Taylor expansion (not shown here) where I have derived that

$$R_{k}<\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}^ke^{x^m}}{\mathrm{d}x^k}}{k !}x^{k} \,. $$

Unfortunately, in need very large $k$ indices such that calculating the derivatives using a computer $\frac{\mathrm{d}^ke^{x^m}}{\mathrm{d}x^k}$ become a hastle (yes this is a weakness with my Taylor expansion). Accordingly, I want to find an upper bound $M_k$ such that

$$R_{k}<\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}^ke^{x^m}}{\mathrm{d}x^k}}{k !}x^{k} \leq\frac{M_k}{k !}x^{k} \,. $$

This introduction leads to the problem statement: **What is your best upper bound for $\frac{\mathrm{d}^ke^{x^m}}{\mathrm{d}x^k}$?**

Details: All of my $m$ values are larger than $1$, typically between $3/2$ and $3$. Furthermore, all of my $x$ values are also positive. I do not need the tightest upper bound.

Comment: When you say $m$ is between 3/2 and 3, is it for the order of the derivative in the question: What is your best upper bound for $d^me^{x^k}/d x^m$?

Comment: I have now fixed the issue. The correct expression is $\frac{\mathrm{d}^ke^{x^m}}{\mathrm{d}x^k}$.

Comment: If you are after an expansion around $x=0$, notice that $$\dfrac{d^k}{dx^k}e^{x^m}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(mn)_k}{n!}x^{mn-k}$$ where $(mn)_k$ is a falling factorial.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for since I can have $x$ values that are significantly larger than 0.